# How to get the address of an array pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, pointers, declaration

I have the following c code:

```
int arr[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
int **pp = &arr;
```

The compiler complains and I don't know why.
Isn't arr a pointer points to an int array? I should be able to assign the address of it to a int**.
Are there any other way to do it?

Comment: `arr` is not a pointer. It is an array. `&arr` is an address of an array, not an address of a pointer. An array may decay to a pointer, but not in this case.

Comment: Because `arr` is an "array of 8 `int`", that means `&arr` is a "pointer to an array of 8 `int`", or `int (*)[8]`. This is *very* different from `int **`.

Comment: As for the "arrays are pointers" confusion, it's because arrays can *decay* to a pointer to its first element. That is, in most contexts plain `arr` is the same as `&arr[0]`, which (being a pointer to a single `int` element) will have the type `int *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't arr a pointer points to an int array?

No, `arr` isn't a pointer at all. `arr` is an array. If you take the address of `arr`, what you get is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer. This would work:

```
int arr[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
int (*pp)[8] = &arr;

// cleaner by using a type alias:
using Arr8 = int[8];
Arr8* pp = &arr;
```

If you want a pointer to pointer, then you must first create a pointer to which you could point at:

```
int*  p  = arr; // same as = &arr[0]
int** pp = &p;
```

> But when I do printf("arr: %x\n", arr);. It actually prints out the starting address of arr. Doesn't that mean it is a variable stores the address of the array?

It does not mean that. `arr` is the array; it doesn't store the address of the array, and the type of the variabe isn't a pointer.

When you pass an array as a variadic argument, it will implicitly convert to a pointer to first element. That is the same implicit conversion that happens in the example above: `int* p = arr;`.

Note that `%x` format specifier requires that the argument is of type `int` (or smimilar). `int*` (which is the resulting type of the implicit conversion) is the wrong type, and hence the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

Comment: But when I do printf("arr: %x\n", arr);. It actually prints out the starting address of arr. Doesn't that mean it is a variable stores the address of the array, i.e. pointer?

Comment: @kjhhgt76: no, what happens is arrays decay as pointers to their first element when passed as function arguments or when used in expressions, with a few exceptions such as `sizeof(arr)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object declared like

```
T x;
```

where `T` is some type specifier then a declarations of a pointer to such an object will look like

```
T *p = &x;
```

Now consider the array

```
int arr[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

using this type def

```
typedef int T[8]:
```

you can rewrite the array declaration like

```
T arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

So a pointer declaration to the object `arr` will look like

```
T *p = &arr;
```

As the type specifier T represents the type `int[8]` then a pointer to an object of this type will have the type `int ( * )[8]`.

So the above declaration looks like

```
int ( *p )[8] = &arr;
```

As for the declaration

```
int **pp;
```

then it can be introduced the following way

```
int *p = arr;
int **pp = &p;
```

That is in the first declaration

```
int *p = arr;
```

the array designator `arr` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. So the pointer `p` is initialized by the address of the first element of the array `arr`.

In turn the pointer `pp` is initialized by the address of the pointer `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and pointers are fundamentally different things:

- think of an array as a street with buildings: each building has a number and the street has a name. In the definition `int arr[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};` The array name `arr` is like the street name and the array elements numbered `0` to `7` are buildings containing each a number.
- a pointer is an object that contains the address to an object: a piece of paper with the address of a building: `char *p = &arr[1];` is akin to writing `1, street arr` on a piece of paper.  As a convenience, but rather a confusing one, `char *p = arr;` is equivalent to `char *p = &arr[0];` just like telling your GPS to go to fifth street will take you to the first house on that street.
- a pointer to a pointer, `int **pp` is a piece of paper where you write the place where to find another piece of paper that has the address of the building in the above paragraph.  This type of pointer may be required in some circumstances, but not as common as regular pointers.
- the definition `int **pp = &arr;` is incorrect because `&arr` is not the address of a pointer. It is the address of the full array `arr`, is a special type of pointer, like a deed is a special type of paper describing an actual property: *the full extend of street `arr`, comprising pavement, sidewalks, lots and constructions erected thereupon.* A pointer to a full array has a special syntax: `int (*p)[8] = &arr;` It is only used in advanced C programming. Most programmers will never need one and might not even understand the syntax, just like in real life, property deeds are seldom seen outside lawyers' offices and official places and mostly abstruse to the *populace*.
- For your purpose, you can define a pointer to `int` and make it point to the beginning of the array: `int *p = arr;` And if you really need a pointer to a pointer to `int`, you can define `pp` as `int **pp = &p;`
- accessing the 3rd element of the array via `pp` will be written `(*pp)[3]` or `pp[0][3]`<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> among other less readable possibilities: `*(*pp + 3)`, `*(3 + *pp)` and downright obscure alternatives: `3[*pp]`, `3[0[pp]]`...

Answer (score 0):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
int arr[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

The above statement creates an array named `arr` of size `8` with `int` elements. The type of the array `arr` is `int [8]`.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement:

```
int **pp = &arr;
```

The following are the things to note about the above statement:

1. On the left hand side, we have a *pointer to a pointer to an `int`* named `pp`. That is, the type of `pp` on the left hand side is `int**`.
2. On the right hand side, we have the expression `&arr`. Since from case 1, we know that the type of the array `arr` is `int [8]`. Therefore, `&arr` is `int (*)[8]` which is read as a *pointer to an array of size 8 with elements of type `int`*.

So essentially, the type on the left hand side is `int**`(from point 1) while the type on the right hand side is `int (*)[8]` (from point 2). That is, the type on the left hand side and the right hand side **don't match**. And this is why the compiler gives us the error saying:

```
error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[8]’ to ‘int**’ in initialization
```

Which means you're trying to initialize `pp` which is an `int**` with the **initializer** of type `int (*)[8]`.

To **solve** this you need to make sure that the type on the left and right hand side **match** as shown below:

```
int arr[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
int (*pp)[8] = &arr; //now the type on rhs and lhs match
```

Now the type of `pp` on the left hand side is `int (*)[8]` which matches with the type of `&arr` on the right hand side and hence this program work fine.

Answer (score -2):

array name is itself the address of [0] index so just make a pointer like this
int *p=array_name;
now just increment the pointer and access the array, like this.
*(array_name + i) where i could be any index which u want to access.

Comment: Arrays decay into pointers in certain contexts, but they are not pointers/addresses.